Electron module not being received
I'm learning electronjs and I'm trying to make a window that creates another window through a button, but when I was testing I noticed that one.js is not importing correctly the remote module. Heres the main.js file:
console.log('main process working');
console.log('main.js');

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const { initialize, enable } = require('@electron/remote/main');

initialize();

function createWindows() {
    let win1 = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    });

    let win2 = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    });

    win1.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'one.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    win2.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'two.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    win1.webContents.openDevTools();
    win2.webContents.openDevTools();

    win1.on('closed', () => {
        win1 = null;
    });

    win2.on('closed', () => {
        win2 = null;
    });

    app.on('browser-window-created', (_, window) => {
        enable(window.webContents);
    });
}

app.on('ready', createWindows);


And here is one.js file:
console.log('From renderer 1');

const { ipcRenderer, remote } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

const { enable } = require('@electron/remote/main');
enable(ipcRenderer);

ipcRenderer.on('electron-module', (event, electron) => {
    console.log('Electron module received');

    const newWindowBtn = document.getElementById('Btn');
    newWindowBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        console.log('Botão clicado!');

        let win3 = new remote.BrowserWindow({
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true,
                contextIsolation: false,
                enableRemoteModule: true
            }
        });

        win3.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'three.html'),
            protocol: 'file',
            slashes: true
        }));

        win3.webContents.openDevTools();
    });
});

ipcRenderer.send('get-electron-module');


Main creates two windows, and window 1 has a button that when clicked should create a new window.
While trying to make this work I noticed that the button doest work.

Actually, when you click the button in one.js it should send a request to the main.js where the win3 will be created.
so your code will look like this in main.js. Add this code
console.log('main process working');
console.log('main.js');

const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const { initialize, enable } = require('@electron/remote/main');

initialize();

function createWindows() {
    let win1 = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
        }
    });

    let win2 = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
        }
    });

    win1.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'one.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    win2.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'two.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    win1.webContents.openDevTools();
    win2.webContents.openDevTools();

    win1.on('closed', () => {
        win1 = null;
    });

    win2.on('closed', () => {
        win2 = null;
    });

    app.on('browser-window-created', (_, window) => {
        enable(window.webContents);
    });

    // Handle IPC to create new window
    ipcMain.on('create-window', () => {
        let win3 = new BrowserWindow({
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true,
                contextIsolation: false,
                enableRemoteModule: true,
                preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
            }
        });

        win3.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'three.html'),
            protocol: 'file',
            slashes: true
        }));

        win3.webContents.openDevTools();
    });
}
app.on('ready', createWindows);

and the one.js will look like
console.log('From renderer 1');

const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

ipcRenderer.on('electron-module', (event, electron) => {
    console.log('Electron module received');

    const newWindowBtn = document.getElementById('Btn');
    newWindowBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        console.log('Botão clicado!');
        ipcRenderer.send('create-window');
    });
});

ipcRenderer.send('get-electron-module')

Preload.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'electron',
    {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
        }
    }
);


I tried the code that you sent me and I still dont get the message "Electron module received" on the opendevtools console on window 1 and when I click the button nothing happens

U can try having a file called preload.js with code I have added it above
